# jQuery: find last 4 letters in string, append it to url, make that row clickable link

Tags: jquery

Hi i'm struggling to make a few separate elements work together to get the final result:

1/ i'm making a variable 'ginfo' - the last 4 letters from a string in a table row

2/ I want to make that row a url, using myurl + ginfo

pretty simple separately, just get it all to work together... thanks for your input

```js
//define 'ginfo' from the table id 'airt' and in the cell 
//containing 'G-' find the last 4 letters.

 var ginfo =("#val_airreg").substring(-4);

// now find the same cell, and append 'ginfo' to the supplied link

jQuery("#val_airreg").click(function(){window.location = ('http://mycustomlink.com/', 'ginfo');});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="odd rowwairreg">
 <th>Aircraft Registration</th>
  <td class="val_airreg">G-CAAM</td>        
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you provide us your html please?

Comment: added the html above, do that help?

Comment: You had en error, you do not need to do `jQuery var ginfo` edited your code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML and your JS are really confusing. But I think [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n55cchah/) is what you are trying to do:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr class="odd rowwairreg">
    <th>Aircraft Registration</th>
    <td class="val_airreg">G-CAAM</td>                              
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var myurl = "http://mycustomlink.com/";

$(".val_airreg").each(function(){
    var ginfo =$(this).text().substring(-4);
  $(this).html('<a href="'+myurl+ginfo+'">'+$(this).text()+'</a>');
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, that's really helped me out. I shortened it to:


`jQuery(".val_airreg").html('<a href="http://www.example.com/'+jQuery(".val_airreg").text().substring(2)+'">'+jQuery(".val_airreg").text()+'</a>'); `